# Double-slit experiment with two different mediums

Tags: visible-light, refraction, double-slit-experiment, wavelength

How the interference pattern will look like in a double-slit experiment done with two different mediums? Air before the slit and glass after the slit.[image]

Comment: Your figure show the diffraction from a single slit while your text talks about a double slit arrangement. Which do you mean?

Comment: @dmckee Double-slit, because I did find simple Double-slit pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The medium that the light travels before it reaches the slits does not affect the result, assuming that the slits are narrow. Only the wavelength of the light matters.

The medium after the slits affects the spacing of the fringes, but qualitatively there is no difference with different media.

Answer (score 3):

There would be **no difference qualitatively**. The pattern is due to path difference after the slit, which would change by a factor of refractive index $n$ and therefore would change the fringe width compared the case of air..

However, if the upper half is filled with water and bottom half is air, the pattern will change. A little analysis will tell the details of that too.

Comment: On the contrary, the fringe spacing changes because the pattern is due to the *phase* difference. The relationship between distance and phase is governed by the frequency and *the speed of the wave*. For light the speed in an medium with index of refraction $n$ is $v = c/n$.

Comment: Oops. You're right. Should I edit the answer or delete it?

Comment: Up to you. You can also edit, wait to see if the downvoers return to amend their votes and delete if the do not.

Comment: No problem. I edited it. Totally deserved the downvotes!